# Expressões regulares com 'grep'

Tags: linux, shell, bash, shell-script

Preciso extrair dados de um texto e estou tentando fazer isso usando grep. Mas a forma de fazer uso de expressões regulares com esse comando são bastante diferentes do que se faz geralmente em Ruby ou JavaScript, e não estou conseguindo fazer o que eu preciso. No texto seguinte:

> Caderno Judiciário do Tribunal Regional do Trabalho da 1ª Região
>
> DIÁRIO ELETRÔNICO DA JUSTIÇA DO TRABALHO PODER JUDICIÁRIO
>
> Nº1697/2015
>
> REPÚBLICA FEDERATIVA DO BRASIL
>
> Data da disponibilização: Quarta-feira, 01 de Abril de 2015.
>
> Tribunal Regional do Trabalho da 1ª Região

Preciso pegar apenas o número que pode ser visto na terceira linha. Este número será posteriormente utilizado para fazer uma requisição a um webservice. Tentei com o grep da seguinte forma:

```
pdftotext Diario_1697_1_1_4_2015.pdf -f 1 -l 1 - | grep -o /Nº(\d+\/\d+)/
```

Pego a primeira página de um arquivo pdf, converto em txt e passo para o comando grep fazer a extração da informação. Mas isso não funciona de jeito nenhum. Alguém sabe dizer a forma correta de fazer isso com o grep ou algum outro comando do bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, o grep é um comando do shell e seus argumentos são strings simples como quaisquer outros. Ao invés de delimitar a regex com `/` você deve usar aspas simples (ou usar aspas duplas, se você for cuidadoso com a expansão de variáveis do shell). Além disso, você precisa escapar suas contrabarras com `\\`.

Em segundo lugar, a sintaxe de regex padrão do grep é meio diferente e bem fraquinha. Por exemplo, ela não entende o `+`, só o `*`. Você pode trocar pra sintaxe de Perl com a flag `-P`

```
grep -P -o 'Nº\\d+/\\d+'
```

ou usar a syntaxe POSIX com `grep -E` ou `egrep`.

```
grep -E -o 'Nº[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+'
grep -E -o 'Nº[0-9]+/[0-9]+'
```

Comment: @JJoao: Funciona no Bash mas não no meu shell padrão que é o Fish. A ;unica contrabarra redundante mesmo era a do `/`